# Remote desktop vertical bars

Tags: remote-desktop

On certain dark backgrounds, remote desktop draws vertical bars, as seen in the following image:

[image: image with dark bars]

These bars change when scrolling / resizing and are only visible on specific colors (like the one seen above).

Let me know if you need any more information, this issue is really irritating.

---

With a filter the vertical bars become more apparent:

[image: image with filter]

I use RDP in full screen mode, on four monitors. Two of these monitors are in 4k, whilst normally the other computer doesn't support more than two monitors. Aside from those bars, the connection works fine though.

The bars don't appear always (but most of the time) and seem to be like a rendering error to me.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Most likely "how to get rid of them?", but "what is the mechanism behind them?" is also possible.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I want to get rid of them, though it would also be interesting to know why they appear in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry but the both images just show some solid colors to me (no gui, scroll bars or something similar to see). I would assume that they are defect.

Comment: @Robert I merely posted some are of the screen, which _should_ display one solid color, to illustrate my point. I did no screenshot of the GUI or similar.

Comment: Ok, now I understand.When I read vertical bars ans scrolling I ended up with scroll bars. I would assume that this is a simple compression problem. The second desktop may use a small tiled image that is compressed via JPEG which then shows some JPEG compression artifacts. Check the RDP client settings on network speed and how the background is generated on the RDP server (solid color or background image).